# How do I make a game object appear on the other side when it leaves the screen?

Tags: unity

I'm doing an assignment for a course and what's required is to include a moving asteroid in the game that starts moving in a random direction and when the asteroid leaves the bottom of the game window it should re-appear at the top of the game window
,so I wrote the script for warping and I applied it to the asteroid and a ship in my game ,then built it to WebGl game. the warping worked fine in the editor for both the ship and the asteroid, while it only worked for the ship in the built game, and I can't figure out what's wrong

this is the script

(ScreenUtils gives the borders of the screen)

```
float Radius;

void Start () {
    Radius = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius;
}
void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    // Make the ship wrap
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    if (position.x - Radius >= ScreenUtils.ScreenRight || position.x + Radius <= ScreenUtils.ScreenLeft)
    {
        position.x *= -1;

    }
    if (position.y -Radius >= ScreenUtils.ScreenTop || position.y + Radius <= ScreenUtils.ScreenBottom)
    {
        position.y *= -1;
    }
    transform.position = position;
}
```

Comment: My first guess would be that your ScreenUtils class is buggy.

Comment: Try logging the values of position.x/y, ScreenUtils.ScreenTop/Right/Bottom/Left, along with the object's name when OnBecameInvisible is called. That will tell you which condition is failing, or whether the method is getting called at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [Screen.width](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html) and [Screen.height](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-height.html) instead of using your own code.  As suggested in the comments, your bug is probably in there.

Alternatively, you can use 8 players, and wrap it around the screen, as scene in this tutorial:  https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/create-an-asteroids-like-screen-wrapping-effect-with-unity--gamedev-15055.